# object detection: is object in the photo, python

Tags: python, pytorch, object-detection

I am trying to detect plants in the photos, i've already labeled photos with plants (with labelImg), but i don't understand how to train model with only background photos, so that when there is no plant here model can tell me so.
Do I need to set labeled box as the size of image?

p.s. new to ml so don't be rude, please)
[image]

Comment: Plese read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.

Comment: Is your task simply to detect if there is a plant seen in a photo? In that case you may not need such labelling. This kind of labelling is useful when you want to detect multiple objects in an image. Also what algorithm are you using for this task?

Comment: I think you are confusing "detection" and "classification" tasks. the later is easier to train.

Comment: i want later to crop this image if there is a plant, and also if there are two and more plants crop them into seperate images, so i need this boxes to be predicted, i though it's a detection problem. but i don't know how to tell when there is no plants in the photo.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had a problem where all my training images were zoomed in on the object. This meant that the training images all had very little background information. Since object detection models use space outside bounding boxes as negative examples of these objects, this meant that the model had no background knowledge. So the model knew what objects were, but didn't know what they were **not**.

So I disagree with @Rika, since sometimes background images are useful. With my example, it worked to introduce background images.

As I already said, object detection models use non-labeled space in an image as negative examples of a certain object. So you have to save annotation files without bounding boxes for background images. In the software you use here (labelImg), you can use *verify image* to say that it saves the annotation file of the image without boxes. So it saves a file that says it should be included in training, but has no bounding box information. The model uses this as negative examples.

Comment: +1 for sharing your experience. Yes, in such cases it may be true indeed. However, based on what she demonstrated here, this is not her issue, and she does not need to do something like this and her detection should go smoothly without a hitch as you can see, the image contains quite a bit of background.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you don't need to do anything in that regard. Just grab the detection data that you created and train your network with it. When it comes to testing, you usually set a threshold for bounding boxes accuracy, because you may get lots of them so you only want the ones with the highest confidence.

Then you get/show the ones with highest bbox accuracies and there your go, you get your detection result and you can do what ever you want like cropping them using the bounding box coordinates you get.

If there are no plants, your network will likely create bboxes with an accuracy below your threshold (very low confidence) and then, you just ignore them.